# Difference between register and setRegister in useEffect dependency

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

Say I set to state with something like

```
const [register, setRegister] = useState(false)

useEffect((=> {
setRegister(true)
},[register or setRegister])
```

What would be the difference in using register or setRegister? If I wanted to depend on this state-changing which would I use? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `register` dependency would cause an infinite loop as each time `register` updated the effect hook callback would be invoked and update `register` again.

```
const [register, setRegister] = useState(false)

useEffect((=> {
  setRegister(true)
},[register])
```

Using `setRegister` dependency would only invoke the callback when `setRegister` reference changed.

```
const [register, setRegister] = useState(false)

useEffect((=> {
  setRegister(true)
},[setRegister])
```

If you wanted to issue a side-effect it would likely be on the value you ***expect*** to change over time, i.e. the local component state `register`, however, you can't blindly use a hook dependency that the hook updates. Use a conditional test on it in order to quell the infinite render looping.

```
const [register, setRegister] = useState(false)

useEffect((=> {
  condition && setRegister(true)
},[condition, register])
```

I also strongly suggest following the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) and add the eslint [plugin](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#eslint-plugin) for hooks, as it will process and help get the correct dependencies in place.